# Maven Project using Eclipse doesn't compile

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have been trying to make a simple Spring project using Eclipse and Maven but I am running into problems. The first one I am trying to resolve is the fact that my code doesn't seem to compile.

For example, if in a class I type `Strrrring test = new String();` there is not error at all displayed by Eclipse. I checked the Properties of the project, under Java Compiler and everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Command Line**

If you have maven installed, you can make maven project working in Eclipse via `mvn` command. At the root of the project run:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

If you want to view the source/doc of the artifact used in your project, you can run following command instead:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true
```

**Eclipse Plugin**

Or if you prefer use Eclipse plugin, you can install [m2eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/) plugin and re-import project

Comment: I am already using m2eclipse. What I did is that I installed the plug-in through Eclipse, then I created a new Maven Project (still through Eclipse) and modified the POM accordingly to use Spring dependencies. Then I did right click on the project, Run As, Maven Build.

Comment: Where did you put your java files? Verify it is under `src/main/java` folder.

Comment: You were totally right. I did not transform my project for eclipse using the mvn eclipse:eclipse command, that was the problem. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer to me, I appreciate. I also did put my source code in the src/main/java folder, the compiler works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project and do run as `maven clean` and `maven install` . It will work fine .